# Laravel 5.2: Using a Number in Attribute Name

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm creating an app that has a couple photos on the User model, named `photo1` and `photo2`. The actual photo files are stored on Amazon S3 and the relative path is stored in the database (example: `10206074968017993/photo1.jpg`). I have an accessor in the User model to retrieve the URL for the photo:

```
public function getPhoto1Attribute()
{
    return 'https://s3-'.env('AMAZON_REGION').'.amazonaws.com/'.env('AMAZON_BUCKET').'/'. $this->photo1;
}
```

This should simply return a full URL of the photo, which should be something like:

`https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/mybucket/10206074968017993/photo1.jpg`

But instead it's throwing an error saying

```
Undefined property: App\\Models\\User::$photo1
```

I think it's the `1` in the `photo1` that is causing the error because if I rename the field to `photo`, the code works great. But because the real app is more complicated than I'm describing here, renaming the fields is not an option. What I can I do?

Comment: what do you see when do dd($this)?

Answer (score 0):

I've just decided to avoid using any integers in my variable names. Though there may be a way to make it work, I just like to keep everything as standardized as possible and I think it's best simply to avoid integers in variable names.